# How to create comma-separated values in 1 column

Tags: mysql

This is my sample table, is it possible to get the distinct value of animals and get its letter with commas and count the letter of specific animals?

Query: Select animals, letter From pet;

```
 +--------------+--------------+
 | animals      | letter       |
 +--------------+--------------+
 | dog          |    d         |
 | dog          |    o         |
 | dog          |    g         |
 | cat          |    c         |
 | cat          |    a         |
 | cat          |    t         |
 | mouse        |    m         |
 | mouse        |    s         |
 | mouse        |    e         |
 +--------------+--------------+
```

This is my expected output, count the letter to get total, count every item before the comma symbol,:

```
 +--------------+--------------+--------------+
 | animals      | letter       |   total      |
 +--------------+--------------+--------------+
 | dog          |    d,o,g     |     3        |
 | cat          |    c,a,t     |     3        |
 | mouse        |    m,s,e     |     3        |
 +--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: How do you expect the letters to be returned in the order you are showing? There is nothing in your tables that put the letters in any order.

Comment: sorry, it should be ascending

Comment: So applying the linked question to your table: `SELECT animals, GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY letter ASC) FROM thetable GROUP BY animals`

Comment: None of your examples are ascending.

Comment: the link answer is correct to my question, but my concern is what if I get the sum of total letter, for example dog = 3, cat = 3, mouse = 3. And my columns will be animals, letter, total

Comment: What does “sum of total letter” mean? The count of letters? Investigate `Count(letter)` and `GROUP BY`. If you can't get it to work, post your efforts to a new question.

Comment: I already revised my question can you take a look again?

Comment: sum(char_length(letter)) as total , but I want is to get seperated by comma(,) as count sample  ab,cd,ef,gh,ih = 5

Comment: Im done thanks for the help ... sum(CHAR_LENGTH(letter) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(letter, ',', '')) + 1) as total